# Windows Form XML Serialization Save Dialog

Tags: c#, xml, windows, forms, streamwriter

im stuck with this stupid form... heres my code. It saves it where the streamwriter wants it to but when i save it where the user wants via the savedialog box is creates the XML but doesnt put anything in it! Can someone have a look as it's starting to wind me up!

```
void SavebuttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream ;
    SaveFileDialog savefile1 = new SaveFileDialog();

    savefile1.Filter = "xml files |*.xml"  ;
    savefile1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
    savefile1.RestoreDirectory = true ;

    if(savefile1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if((myStream = savefile1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            Values v = new Values();
            v.task1_name = this.task1_name.Text;
            v.task1_desc = this.task1_desc.Text;
            v.task1_date = this.task1_date.Value;
            v.task1_time = this.task1_time.Value;
            SaveValues(v);
        }
        myStream.Close();   
    }
}
```

This is the streamwriter...

```
public void SaveValues(Values v)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Values));
    using(TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"E:\TheFileYouWantToStore.xml"))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, v);
    }
...
}
```

EDIT:

```
public class Values 
{
public string task1_name { get; set;}
public string task1_desc { get; set;}
public DateTime task1_date { get; set;}
public DateTime task1_time { get; set;}
}
```

I presume this is the code you meant, im fairly new to coding though mate :(

Comment: Can you try XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"E:\TheFileYouWantToStore.xml")? and post the for Values class.

Comment: Edited my original post, thank you! All the edit on the file did was change the XML to one line of text instead of a nice formatted file.

Comment: It is a basic mistake, the SaveValues() method requires an extra argument so you can pass *myStream*.

Comment: Im not sure how to add this extra argument? You'll have to forgive me, im new to coding. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call `textWriter.close();` after serialize. If you don't close writer it won't apply chenges to file.
By the way you are writing values to **E:\TheFileYouWantToStore.xml**. your save save method does not use users file.

```
public void SaveValues(Values v)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Values));
    using(TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"E:\TheFileYouWantToStore.xml"))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, v);
        textWriter.close();
    }
...
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
if(savefile1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
        Values v = new Values();
        v.task1_name = this.task1_name.Text;
        v.task1_desc = this.task1_desc.Text;
        v.task1_date = this.task1_date.Value;
        v.task1_time = this.task1_time.Value;
        SaveValues(savefile1.FileName, v);
}
```

-

```
public void SaveValues(string fileName, Values v)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Values));
    using(TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, v);
        textWriter.close();
    }
...
}
```

Comment: How do i add the save method to my users file? I dont actually want the streamwriter file... Thanks Though!

Comment: simply you can pass file name to **SaveValues** filename, I edited the code.

Comment: When i use this code it says it's being used by another program... i think i've missed a Close(); somewhere...

Comment: I can't find it -.- stressing me out, could you give me a hand again?

Comment: Please make you sure the save file is not used or already exists.